# Put operation does not work for IBM MQ from camel when using JMSPoolXAConnectionFactory

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq, apache-karaf

We are implementing XA transaction between MQ and database and trying to create a connection factory as a service in karaf as per the below link.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/fr-fr/red_hat_fuse/7.2/html/apache_karaf_transaction_guide/using-jms-connection-factories#manual-deployment-connection-factories

The MQ we are using is IBM and we are connecting to it through camel.
The karaf service is exposed from the same bundle that is going to use it. This is done through blueprint xml file present in the src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint folder.
When we use (through JNDI) the connection factory exposed as a service for setting the connection factory to be used by the JmsComponent of camel, we are able to get message from the queue but not able to put message into the queue. There is no error when the put operation fails and hence, the database gets updated with success. This happens specifically when using JmsPoolXAConnectionFactory as the pool connection factory. If we change it to JmsPoolConnectionFactory, the put operation works and the message is added to the queue.
Below are the sample routes for get and put to queue.

**GET:**

```
from("mq:queue:{{queueName}}")
   .process(new CustomProcessor1())
   .to("direct:call-sp")
.end();

from("direct:call-sp")
   .to("sql-stored:call-sp")
.end();
```

**PUT:**

```
from("vm:send")
   .process(new CustomProcessor2())
   .to("mq:queue:{{queueName}}")
   .to("sql-stored:update-sp")
   .to("vm:nextroute")
.end();
```

**Camel JmsComponent Configuration in camel-context.xml:**

```
<reference id="ptm" interface="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager" />
<reference id="connectionFactory" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=jms/mq)" availability="optional" />
<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="transacted" value="false" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="ptm" />
</bean>
<bean id="mq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="customDestinationResolver" />
</bean>
<bean id="customDestinationResolver" class="com.example.CustomDestinationResolver">
</bean>
```

Is there any put related specific configuration that we are missing?

Answer (score 0):

To coordinate XA transactions, you need a transaction manager which implements the Java Transaction API (JTA).
Therefore, I think you need to use a `JtaTransactionManager` rather than a `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager`.

Check this out:
https://tomd.xyz/camel-xa-transactions-checklist/